# Leave US to Schengen on day 180th without any trouble?

Tags: visas, schengen, 90-180-visa-rules

The 180th day is September 25 in US after staying 90 days in the Schengen Zone. Could I leave US by plane on 25th (180th day) to arrive Schengen next day, 26th, without any trouble?

(Just need to know if it is okay to get on the plane on 25th (180th day) leaving U.S. for Schengen Area next day, 26th that becomes new 90 days.
OK TO LEAVE U.S. on 180th day?)

Comment: I don't think you're asking the right question: It's OK to leave the US on any day.  You're asking about the entry to Schengen.

Comment: @Karlson the question is presumably whether the airline will deny boarding in the US on the 25th because the traveler will not be permitted to enter Schengen on the 25th.  Of course, the airline *should not* deny boarding, because the traveler will not be attempting to enter Schengen on the 25th.  But I can imagine that an airline employee, if given all the facts, might come to the wrong conclusion, so it is entirely possible that the airline *might* deny boarding.

Comment: @phoog I don't think they check for anything except visa validity.

Comment: @Karlson I suppose you are correct.  I've never seen an airline employee try to decipher entry and exit stamps.